# FSCalender Weekend issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, fscalendar

I'm using `FSCalender` in my **ios** project.

When i say

```
_calendar.appearance.weekEndColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

It show Sundays & Saturdays in Orange color, I want to show only **Sundays** as weekend.

Can anyone please help. TIA.

Comment: Saturday and Sunday are weekend.

Comment: but what if we need only sunday as weekend. What i can do for that?